# If no Silverlight, redirect

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have the standard `silverlight` embedded code for handling the SL object in the `Aspx` page.  How can I modify this to redirect to a aspx page if SL is not installed?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
        var appSource = "";
        if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
          appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
        }

        var errorType = args.ErrorType;
        var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

        if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
          return;
        }

        var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " +  appSource + "\n" ;

        errMsg += "Code: "+ iErrorCode + "    \n";
        errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
        errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

        if (errorType == "ParserError") {
            errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
        }
        else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {           
            if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " +  args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
        }

        throw new Error(errMsg);
    }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:fixed;min-width:800px;min-height:600px;">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%" >
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SL.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of that javascript method's body, try using the [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) to redirect to the aspx page you want.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
            window.location.assign("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
        }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:fixed;min-width:800px;min-height:600px;">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%" >
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SL.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, i just found the window.location, but not the assign method. Give a few to find a computer to test that does not have SL.