# How to redirect a user if Silverlight is not installed

Tags: javascript, html, silverlight

I have two versions of a page:  One to show if the user has Silverlight Installed, and one if he doesn't.

So I want to show the first page, and if not, then redirect to the second page.

An answer to this is [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256435/if-no-silverlight-redirect) which the onSilverlightError function.

However, this does not work for me.  I set up a test site at [js1.biz](http://js1.biz) which shows this.  If you go there, and don't have SL installed, you will see the Install Image.  However, I want to redirect the user to  [js1.biz/SLNotINstalled.html](http://js1.biz/SLNotINstalled.html).

So the question is, how to get the user to SLNotInstalled.html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>RedirectIfSLNotInstalled</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#silverlightControlHost {
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Silverlight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
        window.location.assign("http://js1.biz/SLNotInstalled.html");
    }
 </script>

 </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/RedirectIfSLNotInstalled.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Greg

Answer (score 0):

try using `bool = Silverlight.isInstalled( version );` which resides in Silverlight.js

Here's a link to help [Silverlight install microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838126%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#isinstalled)